# Phaser 3 image animation

Tags: javascript, animation, phaser-framework

Ok guys, I have a game to write with Phaser3 and this is my first experience with Phaser.
I need to write a rotating spinner game (where you rotate a spinner and win something). Here is an example image of a spinner for you to get the idea.
[image: Spinner which will rotate]

So now I need to rotate this spinner to some defined angle in some defined seconds. So my question is, does phaser 3 has some rotation animation where I can say rotate picture to some angle in some seconds? Or do I need to deal with it in update(time,delta) function of Phaser3 and do all calculations by myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! You can add a [Tween](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Tweens.Tween.html) that does the rotation in a specific time for you.
Check this [documentation](https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/tween/) for more details.

here's an example of the tween implementation:

```
this.tweens.add({
    targets: image, //your image that must spin
    rotation: rad, //rotation value must be radian
    duration: 1000 //duration is in milliseconds
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rotate a game object with setRotation in the update method. If you want some of the plumbing written for you, you should use phaser tweens. In your use-case it looks like you’d want a phaser timeline as well, which is just tweens executed sequentially. [Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/phaser-timeline-so).

The official documentation to tweens isn’t worth looking at. The rex notes site has much better examples for many phaser topics, including tweens and timelines. [Rex Notes Tweens](https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/tween/).